# VB.Net LINQ Join and GroupBy

Tags: linq, vb.net-2010

I am trying to Group using the LINQ statement. It works good without groupby statement. But adding GroupBy is erring. Tried researching but could not help much. Please advice

```
Dim queryResults = From cust In gBookList, ord In gBookList2
                                   Where cust.Msg_ID = ord.In_Reply_To1
                                   Group cust By cust.EntryID Into Grpd = Group
                                   Select cust.From, cust.Email_To, cust.CC, cust.Subject, cust.Body_255CharsOnly, cust.Received, cust.EntryID, cust.Response_Type, cust.Response_Time_Hrs, cust.Iterations, cust.Mail_Folder, cust.Msg_ID, cust.In_Reply_To, Grpd
```